# Issue with Wordpress blog post not loading on iOS

Tags: php, html, wordpress, http-status-code-404

Very strange issue here. A specific article on our Wordpress site gets to about 80% done loading and completely freezes, and never finishes loading. Only happens on iOS devices, Safari/Chrome doesn't matter.

- Only happens on iOS mobile Safari and Chrome
- Seems to be an issue with the content of the article, or newly published posts in general, as copying and pasting the content into another post gives the same results.

Wondering if there's some iOS-specific issue, some kind of DOM element that's not allowed, or max DOM element length?

Things we've tried with no luck:

- Disabling all plugins and theme
- Trying other devices (does the same thing)
- Clearing both server and device caches
- Removing custom html tags from the content
- Resetting Wordpress permalinks
- Cloning the post
- Copying the content from the post into a new post